# How to efficiently get a lot of users in Amazon Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

We recently hit the request limit on Cognito because we tried to get too many users at once (users are grouped in gamepoules). Currently the only option to get users this way is by [adminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property) in parallel. How can I get for example 200 users where I know the username of without hitting the limit?

I tried assigning the users in a poule to a cognito group so now I can use [listUsersInGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsersInGroup-property). Because of the hard limit of 500 groups per cognito poule this is not an option. We will likely hit 20,000.

Anybody got a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the AWS Cognito Limits [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html), the limit for listing Users is 5 RPS.

However, it is mentioned that the limit is a Soft Limit. If the limit is a Soft Limit, then it could be manually increased by Amazon if you raise a Support Case with them and specify your use-case.

Comment: Thanks, I maybe didn't make this clear enough, I hoped for a better way to get a lot of users instead of requesting a limit increase to 500 RPS.

Comment: There would be no other better way, due to Cognito's design.